# How to correct code style in VS2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Sometimes I have stuff like this in VS

```
if (IsValid)
{
functionA();
  functionB();
  }
```

Well this is not looking good. I want to select these fields (or the field I want to have corrected) and let VS correct the style. Is there a way, somehow I cannot find anything

Answer (score 8):

`Edit` > `Advanced` > `Format Document` (or `Format Selection`) should do a lot of the work for you.

Comment: @LexLi In VS2012 it's actually `(Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D)`

Comment: @JNF, it depends on your keyboard mapping. If you choose Visual C#, then what I said is correct. Obviously you are a VB user :)

Comment: @LexLi, That's what it is? I've wondered why it keeps going back and forth. Last install (11 beta) I chose C# implementation, this time "Web Developers", I guess they decided that means VB. Oh my.